# ERROR: OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: data is too large for key size", when trying to upload cookbook 'learn_chef_iis'

Tags: powershell, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2, chef

I am receiving the following error message: "ERROR: OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: data is too large for key size", when trying to upload cookbook 'learn_chef_iis'. I was following a CHEF tutorial and now I am getting that error and I don't know how to proceed.

I have searched for anything similar to that error on Google as well as this place, and have had no luck.

This is my code:

PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo.chef> knife cookbook upload learn_chef_iis -o ~\chef-repo\cookbooks

ERROR: OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: data too large for key size

I can download the cookbook, but not upload.

I am using Windows Powershell on Operating System Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard via Oracle VM VirtualBox. I am learning CHEF for work.(Total Beginner)

Please can you advise on why I am getting this area? And how I can go around it?

Comment: linking to your tutorial might be helpful.

Comment: Its number 4: Upload your cookbook to the chef server(where I am stuck): https://learn.chef.io/manage-a-node/windows/set-up-your-chef-server/

Comment: Did you mix private and public keys?

Comment: no to the question above. But I have solved the problem now. The information in my knife file was incorrect, the pathway to the cookbook and validation keys. I have managed to upload the cookbook. :) Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no to the question above. But I have solved the problem now. The information in my knife file was incorrect, the pathways to the cookbook and validation keys was wrong. I have managed to upload the cookbook. And several others. :) Thanks for the help.